# Why do generated insert statements use empty_clob() in place of null in CLOB fields?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I have created a table with a CLOB column:

```
create table t2 (a clob);
```

and inserted some values into it:

```
insert into t2 values('A');
insert into t2 values('B');
insert into t2 values(null);
insert into t2 values('C');
insert into t2 values('D');
commit;
```

In SQL Developer I am running query:

```
Select * from T2;
```

The Query Results window shows `(null)` for the null value. I then export the the query results as insert statements. What it generates is:

```
REM INSERTING into T2
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into T2 (A) values ('A');
Insert into T2 (A) values ('B');
Insert into T2 (A) values ( EMPTY_CLOB());
Insert into T2 (A) values ('C');
Insert into T2 (A) values ('D');
```

The same output is produced with the `/*insert*/` query directive and with `set sqlformat insert`.

I don't want `EMPTY_CLOB()` as a value, I want `null` as I inserted before. How can I stop the insert statements being generated like this? Is there a setting which controls this?

Comment: It does the same with the `/*insert*/` modifier and `set sqlformat insert`. Looks like a bug? Might be worth raising on [the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)) or raise a service request through Oracle Support..

Comment: thanks Alex, surely I will raise.